# Function like in_category for custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, conditional-content

I'm trying to display different content depending on the taxonomy that was been selected. For example I have a taxonomy named Type. Inside that taxonomy I have several different children, one is "Photography." I'd like the single of a "Photography" to have a full width instead of it having a sidebar. You can do this in regular Posts by using "if in_category('photography')" but I've spent the past couple hours trying to rig the_terms and the like to function as such.

Thanks in advance for the help.

-Pete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
function has_type( $type, $_post = null ) {
    if ( empty( $type) )
        return false;

    if ( $_post )
        $_post = get_post( $_post );
    else
        $_post =& $GLOBALS['post'];

    if ( !$_post )
        return false;

    $r = is_object_in_term( $_post->ID, 'type', $type);

    if ( is_wp_error( $r ) )
        return false;

    return $r;
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php if ( has_type( 'Photography' ) ) /* do your thing*/ ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 7):

In WP 3.1, you have the handy has_term() function, found in wp-includes/category-template.php.